# ProseMirror -> A Text Rich Text Editor - Trigger an event pure js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, prose-mirror

I am implementing a chrome extension that fills a form basically.

This form has ProseMirror rich text editor in it.

I want to trigger Ctrl+V or paste operation on the text editor, but I couldn’t find any solution to this. these are the things I’ve tried so far:

```
let el = document.querySelector('[contenteditable="true"]')
el.focus()

navigator.clipboard.readText().then((clipText) => {
    // el.innerText = clipText doesn't work
    // el.innerHTML = clipText doesnt't work
    // this.document.execCommand("insertText", false, clipText) doesnt work
})
```

```
document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent({key:'V', ctrlKey: true})) // doesnt work
```

When I do the pasting operation manually, the prose mirror component automatically converts it to a pretty table.

If you want to try -> copy a table then paste it here https://prosemirror-tables.netlify.app/

[image]

How do I trigger the paste event so it would look like as expected case?

Eventhough, this case is related to prose mirror, we may consider this problem for other rich text editors as well.

If I just copy an image and paste it into a rich text editor, picture will be uploaded but it won't work If I try to paste it programmatically

---

Additional screenshot to be clearer
[image]

It look like this If I paste it manually:
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? You've listed four lines of code that "don't work". Are there error messages? Is the formatting incorrect? (your screenshot suggests that this must be the case for at least one of the code lines) Does nothing at all happen?

Comment: I added additional screenshots to be clearer. No error messages, these lines work but not like I expected them to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the following code in Chromium 107.0.5304.121 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit), and it does what you require.

Notes:

- Without the "clipboardRead" permission, `document.execCommand("paste")` doesn't paste the clipboard contents, and returns false.
- The while loop removes all text from the div, so that it only contains the clipboard contents when the content script has finished.
- The div element must be focused to receive the clipboard contents during the paste operation, that's why `element.focus();` is necessary.
- Without the zero-millisecond delay, the removed child nodes re-appear after the paste. This probably has something to do with the task queue.
- [Document.execCommand()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand) is deprecated, so you should avoid using it if possible. Before you ask "Is there any other way to solve this problem, without using Document.execCommand() ?" --- Not to my knowledge, or I would've posted it here. But maybe someone else has a better solution.
- You could probably use [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/) to simulate the user pressing Ctrl-V. That's more complicated, but doesn't use any deprecated features.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Paste",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [ "clipboardRead" ]
}
```

background.js

```
console.log("background.js");
```

content_script.js

```
let element = document.querySelector('[contenteditable="true"]');
if (element) {
    console.log("element.hasChildNodes()", element.hasChildNodes());
    while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
        element.removeChild(element.lastChild)
    }
    element.focus();
    setTimeout(() => {
        let result = document.execCommand("paste");
        console.log("result", result);
    }, 0);
}
else {
    console.log('No elements with contenteditable="true"');
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of permission "clipboardRead". Thank you so much, that worked :).   It also works with images!